# Like button in a iframe app on a fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

i created a fanpage and an iframe-app. With the "app_data" parameter, users can go directly into an article. I put a fbml like button on the article site with this link:

`http://www.facebook.com/testsite?sk=app_123456789&app_data={"oid":"1337"}`

when the user clicks on the link, he like the fanpage and not the article. i have the same issue with the "sharer.php"...

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.facebook.com/testsite?sk=app_123456789&app_data={"oid":"1337"}`

is this impossible or is there a workaround for this problem?

greetings